# PushBullet Nodemcu

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, notify, pushbullet

i working on security alarm system and need to push notify to my phon
and write code according pushbullet api documents but my code not work :

i use both 
"https://api.pushbullet.com" and 
"api.pushbullet.com" for pushbullet_server
and use WiFiClientSecure and WiFiClient for post data

```
void PushBullet::sendNotification(const String title ,const String body){

  String url = "/v2/pushes";

  String msg =  String("{\"body\":\"") + body + String("\",\"title\":\"")+ title + String("\",\"type\":\"note\"}");
  Serial.println(msg);
  String request = String("POST ") + url + "HTTP/1.1\r\n" + 
                   "Host: " + pushbullet_server + "\r\n" +
                   "User-Agent: ESP8266/NodeMCU 0.9\r\n" +
                   "Accept: */*\r\n" +
                   "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" +
                   "Content-Length: "+ msg.length() +"\r\n" +
                   "Access-Token: "+ this->access_token +"\r\n\r\n" +
                   msg;


  Serial.println(request); 
  Serial.println("- connecting to pushing server: " + String(pushbullet_server));
  secure_client.setInsecure();
  if (!secure_client.connect(pushbullet_server, 443)) {
    Serial.println("faile to connect " + pushbullet_server);
      Serial.println(secure_client.readStringUntil('\n'));
    return;
  }

  secure_client.print(request);


  secure_client.stop();

  while(secure_client.connected() && !secure_client.available()) delay(1); //waits for data
  Serial.println(secure_client.readStringUntil('\n'));

  Serial.println("- stopping the client");
}
```

and

WiFiClientSecure secure_client;

`String  pushbullet_server = "https://api.pushbullet.com";`

i also change

`String("POST ") + url + "HTTP/1.1\r\n"` by
`String("GET ") + url + "HTTP/1.1\r\n"`

url  is

```
String url = "/v2/pushes";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved

```
String url = "/v2/pushes";

  String msg = String("{\"body\":\"") + body + String("\",\"title\":\"")+ title + String("\",\"type\":\"note\"}");

  String request = String("POST ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                   "Host: " + this->pushbullet_server + "\r\n" +
                   "User-Agent: ESP8266\r\n" +
                   "Authorization: Bearer " + "o.75WBTSImyZuqQgxgdbE3Tud6ADRzEc6n" + "\r\n" +
                   "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" +
                   "Content-length: " + String(msg.length()) + "\r\n" + 
                   "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

  //"Access-Token: "+ "o.75WBTSImyZuqQgxgdbE3Tud6ADRzEc6n" +"\r\n" +

  Serial.println(request);

  secure_client.setInsecure();

  Serial.println("- connecting to pushing server: " + String(pushbullet_server));

  if (!secure_client.connect(pushbullet_server, 443)) {
    Serial.println("faile to connect " + pushbullet_server);
      Serial.println(secure_client.readStringUntil('\n'));
    return;
  }

  Serial.println("------------------Connect  Succesfull--------------------------------------");

  secure_client.print(request);
  secure_client.print(msg);
```

i forget this line of code : 
"Connection: close\r\n\r\n"

notification send successful